# Replacing ReaderWriterLock with ReaderWriterLockSLim - troubles

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Due to performance problems, I have replaced [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) with [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx). I am experiencing troubles, caused by code that functioned correctly when it was using a RWL.

As you can see, sometimes `MethodA` (which acquires a *write* lock) calls another method (which acquires a *read* lock). The second method is also called from different places, so not always there is lock collision. Previously, AcquiringRead lock doesn't cause that problem.

Is there any solution except from placing "if IsRWheld"?

The problem is something like that:

```
class Avacado
{
   ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

   void MethodA()
   {
      _lock.TryEnterWriteLock(-1);
         LockedList.Add(someItem)
         var result = MethodX();
      _lock.ExitWriteLock();
   }

   object MethodX()
   {
      //if called from MethodA, it will throw an exception
      _lock.TryEnterReadLock(-1);

      //...some stuff with LockedList...
      var result = LockList.Something();

      _lock.ExitReadLock();

      return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The call to MethodX from MethodA qualifies it as recursive use of the lock.
See the remarks on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) for ReaderWriterLockSlim :

> By default, new instances of
>   ReaderWriterLockSlim are created with
>   the `LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion`
>   flag and do not allow recursion. This
>   default policy is recommended for all
>   new development, because recursion
>   introduces unnecessary complications
>   and makes your code more prone to
>   deadlocks. To simplify migration from
>   existing projects that use Monitor or
>   ReaderWriterLock, you can use the
>   `LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion`
>   flag to create instances of
>   ReaderWriterLockSlim that allow
>   recursion.

Answer (score 5):

Another point to consider when replacing `ReaderWriterLock` by `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is that the latter implements `IDisposable`.

This can make the replacement complex - as any types that own a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` must also be `IDisposable`.